# Computing $\int_{0}^1 \prod_{x \in \mathcal{X}} (p_xy + (1-p_x)) dy$

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals

How would I compute this integral:
$$\int_{0}^1 \prod_{x \in \mathcal{X}} (p_xy + (1-p_x)) dy$$
I have tried using the chain rule and not made any headway on that front. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Can you agree that $p_x=\partial p/\partial x$ and explain what $\mathcal{X}$ here is?

Comment: @Fakemistake $p_x$ is just a constant. $\mathcal{X}$ is just a set, the cardinality of which governs the degree of the polynomial whose monomials are of the form $(p_xy+(1-p_x))$.

Comment: The substitution $u = 1 - y$ simplifies the factors of the integrand to the form $1-p_x u$. The product can then be expanded as a polynomial in $u$, with coefficients expressed as [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of the $p_i$. The integration of the expanded polynomial is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $|\chi|<\infty.$

If we are able to rewrite the product as follows
$$\prod_{x\in\chi}(p_xy+(1-p_x))=\sum_{n=0}^{|\chi|}a_ny^n$$
then the integral is very easy to compute and it results in
$$\int_0^1\prod_{x\in\chi}(p_xy+(1-p_x))dy=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{|\chi|}a_ny^ndy=\sum_{n=0}^{|\chi|}\frac{a_n}{n+1}.$$
Now the terms $a_n$ are those where you multiply exactly $n$ $p_xy$ together and $|\chi|-n$ terms of the form $(1-p_x)$ (look at the degreee). Thus
$$a_n=\sum_{A\subset \chi\\ |A|=n}\prod_{p_x\in A} p_x\cdot\prod_{p_x\notin A}(1-p_x)$$